# Spring MVC With RestTemplate - unexplained delay on post (load test)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, load, resttemplate

I'm encountering a very bizzare performance discrepency.
I'm running a load test on my local machine.
2 different web applications are communicating via restTemplate of spring.(a single tomcat server is running both web apps)

Here is the bizzare flow in a "load test" of only 100  concurrent players:

A) webapp#1 uses the following call:

```
GameResponseDTO result = template.postForObject(
                URLS.GAME_SERVER_URL + "/GameServer/game/play/",
                gameRequestDTO,
                GameResponseDTO.class);
```

B) webapp#2 controller recieves this rest call and returns a result object after less than 100ms!

C) the result returns to webapp#1 after 9000ms even though the handle of webapp#2 took less than 100ms!

- Questions:

1) Any ideas what can cause this? bear in mind both apps are on the same machine (no real networking duration)

2) Any ideas on what else should i check?

3) is it possible this issue is caused by @Transactional \ marshaling of json response? if so how can i test it?
Thanks!

Comment: There was a similar question (not a duplicate) on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277138/spring-resttemplate-slow-response-time

Comment: How do you time the 100ms in webapp2 (what are the start and end points for measuring)?

Comment: I start the measure as soon as the call reaches to the controller, i end the time measurments as soon as the controller recieves the result object from the service. (controller -> service -> controller)

Answer (score 0):

Please check size of your result object and whether it contains any complex member variables other than java p primitives

Comment: The object i'm sending has 2 fields (integers)

Comment: @Urbanleg what was the reason for delay?